# How to use bootstrap Glyphicons in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wanted to add an icon to my navbar in mvc but after i added

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>
```

nothing came out is there some package is didn't install or is just broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this within your site, you need to do the following:

1.Download `bootstrap.icon-large.min.css` and place it in the same directory as `bootstrap.css` file.

2.Download glyphicons.png and place it in the same directory as `glyphicons-halflings.png`.

3.Add the following CSS definition under the `bootstrap.css` call

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.icon-large.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: 1.Can i add the 'bootstrap.icon-large.min.css' into the bundle.config   2.The .png i need to download the individual or the whole icon in one .png

Comment: 1. Yes ! you can add it to the bundle. 2. You have to download the individual.